# Identify what button triggered new frame

Tags: java, android

Below is my code

```
startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showTimePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });

endBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showTimePickerDialog(view);
    }
});


public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String time = String.format("%02d", hourOfDay) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minute);
    Log.d("DTAG", "Time Selected:" + time);
    //How to know here what button triggered the new fragment
}
```

How can I know what `button` triggered the action without setting some new values outside functions? Like `startBtnClicked=true;`

Comment: it is not very clear. Please add more information in your question for better understanding

Comment: you can set a tag which will identify each button and then you can pull it from your method showTimePickerDialog like (Button) v.getTag

Comment: @Roljhon But I need this data at onTimeSet and not at showTimePickerDialog

Comment: @Dim then save it on a global variable from the showTimePickerDialog method since that is where you can differentiate the clicked button and from that onTimeSet method check the current value if its start or end button.